# Identify sci-fi short story about hired assassin hunted after a botched job fleeing in self driving car

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The premise is a bit weird: the assassin lands at the airport after a failed mission knowing that he is marked for death unless he can reach somewhere first. The point of the story is how proud he is about being self-sufficient and driving his own car instead of taking public transportation. The car in question is in fact self driving, and at times remote controlled by the authorities.

I want to show this story to my friends who are proud of driving stick-shift :)